# how to import d3.js to angular 2?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular, npm

I'm using the final version of angular 2 with out angular cli and webpack.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'; //ERROR: Cannot find module 'd3'
```

I installed d3:
 npm install d3 --save

what is the problem?

---

system.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'map':                        'npm:d3',
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      '@ngrx':                      'npm:@ngrx',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      d3: {
        main: 'd3',
        format: 'global'
      },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        main: '/bundles/Rx.min.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      '@ngrx/core': {
        main: 'bundles/core.min.umd.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      '@ngrx/store': {
        main: 'bundles/store.min.umd.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      '@ngrx/effects': {
        main: 'index.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      '@ngrx/store-devtools': {
        main: 'bundles/store-devtools.min.umd.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      '@ngrx/store-log-monitor': {
        main: 'bundles/store-log-monitor.min.umd.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      '@ngrx/router-store': {
        main: 'bundles/router-store.min.umd.js',
        format: 'cjs'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json?

Comment: I added the tsconfig.json to the question details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typings install --global --save dt~d3
```

You have a JavaScript library(d3) in your code and you are trying to import it in TypeScript code. TypeScript does not know the "shape" of that library and you need to install a [TypeScript definition file](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/19/using-typescripts-type-definition-files-to-get-tooling-support-for-plain-javascript#static-typing-for-existing-javascript-libraries) for that to work. It does not have any functionality, just the "shape" of the library so that the TypeScript compiler knows what it's working with.

Comment: Thanks for the try but webstorm still can't find the module d3.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense... let me try it.

Comment: Try this:
typings install --global --save dt~d3

Comment: Working! Thanks! Is there a chance you explain what does the last command do? (+add the last command to your asnwer)